# AlarmManager still triggering alarm after canceling the associated service and PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-service, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have a service which uses `PendinIntent` and `AlarmManager` to launch another activity after a fixed period of time.

Here is the relevant code of the service:

```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  //Create a calendar
       cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);         //Add the set minutes to the alarm

       Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, alarmRingLayout.class);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1234, dialogIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
       am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

When the service starts, I also set up a notification which has the a button that can cancel the service incase the user does not want the activity to launch. 
On click of the "cancel" button, `stopService()` is called:

`stopService(new Intent(StopPowerNapAlarmService.this, PowerNapAlarmService.class));`

`onDestroy()` has the following code which cancels the notification and calls `stopSelf()`
It also *tries* to cancel the `PendingIntent` and `AlarmManager`.

The problem is that the Activity opens up even after after `onDestroy` is called. I believe the `PendingIntent` and/or `AlarmManager` are not getting canceled.

Here is the code for `onDestroy()`:

```
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       CancelNotification(this, 0);

       //Cancel the pending intent and AlarmManager
       Intent myntent = new Intent(PowerNapAlarmService.this, PowerNapAlarmService.class);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
              1234, myntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       pendingIntent.cancel();
       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       am.cancel(pendingIntent);

       stopSelf();
   }
```

What is going wrong over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going wrong over here?

Your `Intent` objects are different, so your `PendingIntent` objects are different. This, in turn, means that you are working with different alarms. The first `Intent` points to an `alarmRingLayout.class` activity. The second `Intent` points to a `BroadcastReceiver` oddly named `PowerNapAlarmService`.

If you want to `cancel()` the `alarmRingLayout` alarm, create an activity `PendingIntent` for `alarmRingLayout`, and use that with `cancel()`.

Also, please get rid of `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()`, as that is not needed and could conceivably cause problems.